# Make UnitPrice read Only using triggers

Tags: trigger, validation, validation-rule, quote, quotelineitem

Currently I am trying to block certain profiles from changing UnitPrice within Quote. I used validation rules under customize> QuoteLineItem and worked perfectly fine. However those validation rules only work when the product has been already added. The Issue I have right now; is when the user adds a product inside quote by clicking on "Add Line Item" they are prompted to a page where they can enter quantity. There is also a UnitPrice there as well. They are still allowed to change the price. I am not sure how i can access that page and how I can disable that field within the page. I thought the below trigger could do it, but I am not sure how to add certain profile or even where do i add that trigger to for this page.

[image: changing the UnitPrice there]

Check if the value of "UnitPrice" has changed like

```
if(trigger.new[0].UnitPrice != trigger.old[0]).UnitPrice)
{
trigger.new[0].addError('You can not change the value of SalesPrice');
}
```

currently this is what I have as validation rule that stops user from changing price after the lineItem has been added

```
OR(AND(ISCHANGED(UnitPrice),$UserRole.Id  = "00E..."),AND(ISCHANGED(UnitPrice),$UserRole.Id  = "00E..."))
```

**Updated:**
the new validation rule using my own profile ID as a test case

```
OR(
    AND(ISNEW(), NOT(ISNULL(UnitPrice)),
    AND(NOT(ISNEW()), ISCHANGED(UnitPrice)),$UserRole.Id = "00EG00....")
)
```

Comment: Don't ever use hard-coded Ids except as a last resort. Here, you should use `$UserRole.DeveloperName` instead of `$UserRole.Id`. Are you testing as someone with a blacklisted role?

Comment: No I have many users under a role and I dont want any of them to have the option to change the price at any time during of quote creation and adding line item. @AdrianLarson

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are trying to do...that's what I mean by blacklist. Are you testing as a user who has a role that should be disallowed?

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes I added my own role ID, admin and I am testing it under my own name

Comment: @AdrianLarson this is the new validation rule I added with my own profileId OR(
    AND(ISNEW(), NOT(ISNULL(UnitPrice)),
    AND(NOT(ISNEW()), ISCHANGED(UnitPrice)),$UserRole.Id = "00EG00....")
)

Comment: Please don't dump additional attempts into the comments, but rather [edit] them into your post.

Comment: @AdrianLarson sure ill update now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with your `Validation Rule`. You just need to add a clause for `ISNEW`.

```
OR(
    AND(ISNEW(), NOT(ISNULL(UnitPrice)),
    ISCHANGED(UnitPrice)
)
```

If you want to add a `UserRole` blacklist to the mix, I recommend  the following:

```
AND(
    1 = CASE($UserRole.DeveloperName,
        "Admin", 1,
        "OtherBlacklistedRole, 1,
        "etc...", 1,
        0
    ),
    OR(
        AND(ISNEW(), NOT(ISNULL(UnitPrice)),
        ISCHANGED(UnitPrice)
    )
)
```

Note that both formulas should work equally well for the insert and update case. If you really insist on keeping the insert and update rules separate, they would be:

**Insert Rule**

```
AND(
    1 = CASE($UserRole.DeveloperName,
        "Admin", 1,
        "OtherBlacklistedRole, 1,
        "etc...", 1,
        0
    ),
    ISNEW(),
    NOT(ISNULL(UnitPrice))
)
```

**Update Rule**

```
AND(
    1 = CASE($UserRole.DeveloperName,
        "Admin", 1,
        "OtherBlacklistedRole, 1,
        "etc...", 1,
        0
    ),
    ISCHANGED(UnitPrice)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I write this as an individual validation rule, would it override the other one. I just added that as its own and it didnt work I was just wondering. I am adding this under quoteLineItem

Comment: Can you be more specific about what didn't work?

Comment: So I added what you have to validation rules (Under QuoteLineItem) and then I went and try to add a new product to a quote by clicking on"Add Line Item" change the sales price(UnitPrice) and saved it. it didnt stop me.  I am going to update my question with what I have so far. I added your rule as a new rule besides what I already had

Comment: @Metawaa Take a look at the updated formula...

Comment: Do you mind to tell me what this does $UserRole.DeveloperName and 1,0

Comment: It's just checking against the `DeveloperName` field instead of hardcoding the Ids. And using a `CASE` statement is just a more efficient way to write `OR($UserRole.DeveloperName="Admin", $UserRole.DeveloperName="etc...")`.

Comment: Thank you so much, so in this case I just use role name of mine "Salesforce_Administrator"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50613/discussion-between-metawaa-and-adrian-larson).